# How can I know that an iframe has finished loading?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I used iframe to download file from my web application when a button is clicked.

Here is my code:

```
    iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.src = "Report/ExportFile.aspx";
    iframe.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

I want to call a function in the parent page (the one that includes the iframe), to stop my loading animation.

I need to know when the iframe finish loading, and the save/open dialog pops up in order to stop it.

I tried to stop the animation inside iframe.onload = function() { //close },
but the problem is that inside the iframe page load I have this code:

```
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx");
    Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
```

so the page execution terminates.

Does anyone have a solution how can I know that the iframe has loaded?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get some client side scripting involved:

```
$("#iFrameId").load(function (){ 
    // Do something, probably an AJAX request in your case
});
```

Comment: The problem with it is that this code never hits because Response.End() stops the execution of the page.

Comment: ...which prevents the load from triggering.... I agree @Inbal.....did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to have a method in the iframe javascript that you can call when the iframe is finished loading.  Inside of this method, call a method on the parent page:

```
var iFrameLoaded = function () {
    parent.stopLoadingAnimation();
};
```

To continue loading the page after your code in iframe's page load, drop the Response.End() so that execution will continue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't drop the Response.End, because than the export file process won't complete. Do you have any other idea how to solve it?

Answer (score -2):

you can see this, jquery iframeloaded.

`function iframeLoaded() {
    alert("Iframe loaded!");
}`

Good Luck!